# Pandas: how to explode a row of list elements into their own separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {

'a' : [['Foo', 49.51, -120.69], ['Foo', 49.51, -120.69], ['Foo', 49.51, -120.69], ['Foo', 49.51, -120.69]],
'b' : [['YLK', 44.48, -79.55], ['HG76', 44.60, -65.76], ['DEF', 49.52, -113.99], ['YXZ', 47.96, -84.78]],
'c' : [1628.931942, 1949.748061, 2556.622213, 301.193418]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    a                       b                       c
0   [Foo, 49.51, -120.69]   [YLK, 44.48, -79.55]    1628.931942
1   [Foo, 49.51, -120.69]   [HG76, 44.6, -65.76]    1949.748061
2   [Foo, 49.51, -120.69]   [DEF, 49.52, -113.99]   2556.622213
3   [Foo, 49.51, -120.69]   [YXZ, 47.96, -84.78]    301.193418
```

I would like to split out columns `a` and `b` such that their elements become their own columns, like this:

```
    a     b       c         d       e        f         g
0   Foo   49.51   -120.69   YLK     44.48    -79.55    1628.931942
1   Foo   49.51   -120.69   HG76    44.6     -65.76    1949.748061
2   Foo   49.51   -120.69   DEF     49.52    -113.99   2556.622213
3   Foo   49.51   -120.69   YXZ     47.96    -84.78    301.193418
```

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do `DataFrame` call

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('a').tolist(),index = df.index))
Out[215]: 
                       b            c    0      1       2
0   [YLK, 44.48, -79.55]  1628.931942  Foo  49.51 -120.69
1   [HG76, 44.6, -65.76]  1949.748061  Foo  49.51 -120.69
2  [DEF, 49.52, -113.99]  2556.622213  Foo  49.51 -120.69
3   [YXZ, 47.96, -84.78]   301.193418  Foo  49.51 -120.69
```

Comment: Thanks, @BENY.  How would I **also** explode column b?  (this stays as a list using your solution)

Comment: @zeroes_ones df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('b').tolist(),index = df.index))

Comment: Sorry, do I call those two lines one right after the other?  I'm getting an error when I try to do that.  (`ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='object')`)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use the `.to_list()` method of a `pandas.Series` and then just assign the values to new columns like this:

```
df[["a1", "a2", "a3"]] = df["a"].to_list()
df[["b1", "b2", "b3"]] = df["b"].to_list()
```

In one line:

```
df[["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3"]] = (df["a"] + df["b"]).to_list()
```

If you dont need a and b you can drop it

```
df.drop(columns=["a", "b"], inplace=True)
```